# Random variables, inequalities involving them and medians thereof (II)

Tags: probability, median, proof

I have a continuous function $A$ for which it holds that:

$$x\in S\implies A(x)<0$$

$$x\in T\implies A(x)>0$$

Of course, $S$ and $T$ don't intersect.

Now consider two continuous distributions functions $F_x$ and $G_y$, both defined on the real line.

For both, it holds that:

$$1>\int_{S}f_x(x)dx+\int_{T}f_x(x)dx>1/2$$
$$1>\int_{S}g_y(y)dy+\int_{T}g_y(y)dy>1/2$$
(both distributions have more than half their respective masses on $T$ and $S$.)

However, we also have that:

$$\int_{S}f_x(x)dx>\int_{S}g_x(x)dx\text{ and }\int_{T}f_x(x)dx<\int_{T}g_x(x)dx$$
($F_x$ has more (less) mass on $S$ ($T$) than $G_y$.)

My questions is: under the conditions above, is it always true that:

$$\mbox{med}_{X\sim F_x}A(X)\leq\mbox{med}_{Y\sim G_y}A(Y)$$

(here $\sim F$ means iid sample from $F$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,

I will give a counterexample with discrete distributions, for simplicity, which can be easily turned into a counterexample with continuous distributions.
$$
A(x) = x\\
S = {-2}\\
T = {2}\\
$$

For $X\sim F_x$, $P(X=-2)=1/3$, $P(X=1)=5/12$, and $P(X=2)=1/4$.

For $Y\sim G_y$, $P(Y=-2)=1/4$, $P(Y=-1)=5/12$, and $P(Y=2)=1/3$.

Each distribution has more than half its mass on $S\cup T$.  $F_x$ has more on $S$, and $G_y$ has more on $T$.

$$
\mbox{med}_{X\sim F_x}A(X) = \mbox{med}_{X\sim F_x}X = 1 > -1 = \mbox{med}_{Y\sim F_y}Y = \mbox{med}_{Y\sim G_y}A(Y)
$$

**Intuition:**

Saying anything about the median given information on only part of a distribution is incredibly hard.  Think about it this way: given a distribution, you can fix the median (with some small amount of mass on either side), and take the remaining mass and move it anywhere so long as it doesn't cross the median.  It's like counterexample heaven.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Specially for the intuition part! I still need to think to be sure it holds when F, G are continuous (it is incredibly late here).

Comment: Just put little bumps at the numbers I specified.  Thanks for the positive feedback.  I get worried that the intuition part is condescending but I think a counter example without some intuitive explanation can be pretty worthless.

Comment: yes sure, but in my problem I also have that F and G are both unimodal in my problem (I didn't though it mattered), so I have to connect the number you specified by lines. Welcome to CV!